# How do I transfer bitpay wallet from one machine to another (PC or oth. type of device)

Tags: wallet, wallet.dat, bitpay

I have a new PC that I want to host my bitpay wallet on, so I need to migrate it from the current machine. I did a superficial search on the current machine for `*wallet.dat*` file in my `C:` drive w/ `dir /s *wallet.dat*` but it seems like bitpay uses a different storage model.

**Question:** How do I migrate bitpay wallet from any type of device to another device of any type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. There are 3 ways to do that in bitpay.

- Export by scanning the QR code that can be found in: `Settings > "Wallet name" > 
  More options > Export wallet`
- Export to file w/ password. Same path as before.
- The backup option w/ the backup phrase, in: `Settings > Backup`